# Tying to post request with some parameters,getting issue like Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)'

Tags: json, swift, parsing, nsobject, nsjsonserialization

I am having some parameters ,need to post request of repeatInfo.Getting error as  Invalid type in JSON write (__SwiftValue)'

below is the post request parameters.

```
{    
     "meetingName": "Updated meeting name",
     "startDateTime": "Tue Jul 27 2020 11:40:30 GMT+0530 (India 
      Standard Time)",
     "priority": "Medium",
     "endDateTime": "Tue Jul 27 2020 11:40:30 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
     "isScheduled": true,
     "isRepeated": false,
     "repeatInfo": {
     "repeatType": "Weekly",
     "weekPattern":[ "Mon","tue"],
     "endRecurrance": "Tue Jul 27 2020 11:40:30 GMT+0530 (India 
       Standard Time)"
     } 
   }
```

Below is the class for repeatInfo.

```
 class RepeatInfo: NSObject, Codable {
                 dynamic var repeatType: String?
                 dynamic var endRecurrance : String?
                 dynamic var weekPattern: [String]?

            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                  case repeatType = "repeatType"
                  case endRecurrance = "endRecurrance"
                  case weekPattern = "weekPattern"
               }
               convenience init(repeatType : String?, endRecurrance : String?, weekPattern : 
           [String]?) {

                     self.init()
                     self.repeatType = repeatType
                     self.endRecurrance = endRecurrance
                     self.weekPattern = weekPattern
                    }
             convenience required init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {

                  let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
                  let repeatType = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .repeatType)
                  let endRecurrance = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .endRecurrance)
                  let weekPattern  = try container.decode([String].self, forKey: .weekPattern )
                  self.init(repeatType: repeatType, endRecurrance: endRecurrance, weekPattern: weekPattern )
            }
        }
```

Comment: please replace the image with text format..

Comment: changed to textformat @BenRockey

Comment: As the error says you cannot serialize a custom struct to something the parameter type supports.

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
// MARK: - Meeting
struct Meeting: Codable {
    let meetingName, startDateTime, priority, endDateTime: String
    let isScheduled, isRepeated: Bool
    let repeatInfo: RepeatInfo
}

// MARK: - RepeatInfo
struct RepeatInfo: Codable {
    let repeatType: String
    let weekPattern: [String]
    let endRecurrance: String
}
```